# Character difference between 'buy' and 'sell'

Tags: characters, difference, glyph-origin

The characters for 'buy' and 'sell',  seem to have a subtle difference in the character.

- 買/买 (buy)
- 賣/卖 (sell)

I want to know, what's the significance of the radial  on top of the sell? How does adding that change 'buy' into 'sell'?

Comment: The two does **not** pronounce the same. 买(mǎi) and 卖(mài) are different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mnemonic for differentiating 买 and 卖](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/9740/mnemonic-for-differentiating-%e4%b9%b0-and-%e5%8d%96)

Comment: check 字源字形 of  zdic.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original form of the top part of 賣 is 出.

《說文》

> 作。出物貨也。从出从買。

出物貨也：
出：拿出 take out
物：物品 goods
貨：交易 to trade

[image]

買
《說文》

> 作，市也。

市：做買賣。to trade

「買」本指商品交易，兼有「買、賣」二義，後來專指交易中的買入。
買 refers to the commodity trading activities, both "to buy and to sell", and later refers specifically to purchase transactions.

source: 《康熙字典》《字源》

Comment: Is the first character bone script?

Comment: It's noted below the word, 《说文》小篆, which is 《说文解字》小篆体, small seal script.

Answer (score -2):

Your post has typo,

Should be like:

> 买/買(buy) 卖/ 賣 (sell)

The former one is the simplified Chinese, the later one is traditional Chinese, the 1st pair simply means "buy" or "purchase", the 2nd pair means "sell"